# Vector Subscript out of range in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, opencv, vector

I am facing problem while loading vector array to vector RGB array.

After 
`rgbv = pointcloud_RGB[i];` I am getting an error "Vector subscript is out of range". Can someone guide me please.

Regards

Suhas

```
const std::vector<cv::Vec3b>& pointcloud_RGB;

for (unsigned int i=0; i<points.size(); i++) {
    cv::Vec3b rgbv(255,255,255);
    if (pointcloud_RGB.size() >= i) {
        rgbv = pointcloud_RGB[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: I can understand that English is not your primary language (it's not mine, either), but at least check your question's title for spelling mistakes, next time, please :)

Comment: Thanks for the replay. Yes I am very poor in English but I didn't get you. Which spelling ? Of-course I edited, I just changed the sentence arrangement but I didn't find that spelling mistake. Can you please let me know, I can change it.

Comment: I corrected your title June 26th :) so there's no spelling mistake there any more.

Answer (score 2):

You have an off-by-one error.

If `pointcloud_RGB.size() == i`, then `i` is one element past the end of the vector.

To fix this, just change your condition from this:

```
if (pointcloud_RGB.size() >= i) {
```

To this:

```
if (pointcloud_RGB.size() > i) {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (unsigned int i=0; i<points.size(); i++) {
    cv::Vec3b rgbv(255,255,255);
    if (i<pointcloud_RGB.size() ) {
        rgbv = pointcloud_RGB[i];
    }
}
```

This will fix, out of bound error